# Show reaction count on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm using this package as a voting system, I use Laravel 7, I avoid pasting the various codes because you can find all the documentation here: https://github.com/qirolab/laravel-reactions

I was testing the whole thing, but can't show a certain reaction count? I mean, $article->reactionSummary() shows an array of all reactions, but I'd like to show the "Like" reaction count.

- https://github.com/qirolab/laravel-reactions#reaction-summery-on-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve a value from your `reactionSummary` you can do:

```php
$reactionSummary = $article->reaction_summary->toArray();
$likesCount = $reactionSummary['like'];
```

as the docs says: **[Reaction summary on model](https://github.com/qirolab/laravel-reactions#reaction-summary-on-model)**

> ```php
> $article->reactionSummary();
> $article->reaction_summary;
>
> // example
> $article->reaction_summary->toArray();
> // output
> /*
> [
>    "like" => 5,
>    "dislike" => 2,
>    "clap" => 4,
>    "hooray" => 1
> ]
> */
> ```

The `$article->reaction_summary->toArray();` will gives you an array containing a `like` key and so on.

**EDIT 1**:

If the key `like` does not exists you can do something like this:

```php
$reactionSummary = $article->reaction_summary->toArray();
$likesCount = 0;
if (array_key_exists('like', $reactionSummary)) {
   $likesCount = $reactionSummary['like'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, if there is no element for that type of reaction, it shows an error instead of showing '0'. Is there a way to do this by avoiding lines of code? Thank you

Comment: @DanieleTedeschi check the **Edit 1** :).